Powershell -and Statement
I am new to Powershell and converting all my VBScript code to Powershell.
I am reading in 2 arrays, comparing the text and deciding whether to copy the text from array In1 or In2 based on the greater length. I only mention below the relevant code that is not performing as I expected rather than the whole program. I have spend 2 days inserting displays to identify the problem. I want the loop to stop when BOTH conditions have been met (ie $CurrLine1 equals $LastLine1 AND ($CurrLine2 equals $LastLine2). Instead the loop stops when only the second condition is met, so it does not read in the remainder of In1. it has stopped when 7 lt 13 and 10 lt 10.
Can someone please tell me what to change? Thanks
While (($CurrLine1 -lt $LastLine1) -and ($CurrLine2 -lt $LastLine2))
{
    If (($In1[$CurrLine1]).Substring(0, ($In1[$CurrLine1]).Length) -eq ($In2[$CurrLine2]).Substring(0, ($In1[$CurrLine1]).Length)) 
    {
        # Merge data from $In2 into $Out1
        $Out1[$CurrLine3] = $In2[$CurrLine2]
        $CurrLine1++
        $CurrLine2++
    }
    Elseif (($In1[$CurrLine1]).Substring(0, ($In1[$CurrLine1]).Length) -lt ($In2[$CurrLine2]).Substring(0, ($In1[$CurrLine1]).Length)) 
    {
        # Insert new record from In1 into Out1
        $Out1[$CurrLine3] = $In1[$CurrLine1]
        $CurrLine1++
    }
    Else 
    {
        # Drop record from In2 as presumably film deleted
        $CurrLine2++
    }
}

The -and works like a -or. I want both conditions to be met not the first or the second condition only.

How are the CurrLine and LastLine variables initialized? Does LastLine ever change?

Looks like your description doesn't match the example. Logically, if you "want to loop to stop when BOTH conditions have been met" (if ($CurrLine1-ge ... -AND $CurrLine2 -ge ...) { break }) the operator changes when you want to do the opposite (continue/while): while ($CurrLine1-lt ... -OR $CurrLine2 -lt ...) { ....

There are a few issues with your code. To start: we don't know anything about LastLine1, LastLine2 and CurrLine3. Second: they way the code is written, the content of $Out1[$CurrLine3] will be overwritten, instead of items being added to it(on this topic you might want to make it a List instead of an Array). Third, to compare string length you can simply use If ($In1[$CurrLine1].Length -eq $In2[$CurrLine2].Length) . Last: what iRon said.

When I use While (($CurrLine1 -lt $LastLine1) -and ($CurrLine2 -lt $LastLine2))

When I use      While (($CurrLine1 -lt $LastLine1) -and ($CurrLine2 -lt $LastLine2))     it runs ok but stops too soon because the first statement has not been been. And yet with -and it should be. If I change both -lt to -ge none of the steps run.

The variables are values are all set up correctly as the code does work ok, it just terminates early. Thanks about "the content of $Out1[$CurrLine3] will be overwritten" you are right it was overwriting $Out1[0] . So far nothing explains why the While statements don't work correctly.  7 lt 13 -and 10 -lt 10 and it stops   when it should run until 13 lt 13 -and 10 lt 10. I have 6 missing records from In1 that should have been added  to Out1

HotStuff669, you need to start with the first comment from @lit: if the concerned variables are not initialized, you start with $null -lt $null which is essential $false Meaning that the other condition doesn't matter, it will never start the while loop (which is a part of your problem description). Please add that to your script and the [mcve] in your question.

This site will not allow me to paste all the code. But the variables etc are all initialised ok. Everything works ok except that this loop does not stop when both statements are False. How do I get it to keep running until the first statement is also False? Or can I use other than  [While .. If ... Elseif ... Else] which might work.

What are the initial values? Part of making an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example) is to make it as easy as possible for someone to see the problem. This typically includes providing example data.

I found the While statement with the -and would never work. So I eventually found another condition with only one While statement that did work. Thanks for the assistance everyone. This is my first venture into Powershell, but understanding the correct use of brackets  was once bad enough for newbies, but now we have "curly brackets" and "square brackets" as well and the use of -eq -gt -lt etc are totally different to = gt lt is all mind blowing.  The days when learning a new programming language was easy has long gone. It took me 5 days to get 81 lines to work correctly. Thanks again.
